# How to make link on text and not on cell with tabularx

Tags: tables, hyperref, tabularx

Consider the following:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|X|l|} 
        Text spanning over multiple lines.
        Text spanning over multiple lines.
        Text spanning over multiple lines.
        Text spanning over multiple lines.
        &
        \url{test.com}
    \end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

it produces:

[image]

**Is there any way to make the border be only around `test.com`, and not take the cell's size?**

Comment: put a box around the url: `\mbox{\url{test.com}}`

Comment: Excellent, thanks! @UlrikeFischer